# Многоуровневая AHAH форма в Drupal 6

Tags: drupal, php

Как сделать многоуровневую динамическую форму в друпале через Form API. Например сначала выбираем страну, затем область и в конце город ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Общий принцип.

Вариант 1.
На событие `onChange` первого select'а вешается javascript функция, которая отправит значение на сервер, а ответ встроит во второй select. Проще всего такое делать при помощи того же jQuery.

Вариант 2. Если форма не большая (хотя наверно это не ваш случай) - все значения в виде вложенных массивов (js естественно) загружаются на страницу, где при выборе из первого селекта, выбираются данные из массивов и суются во второй селект. Плюсы этого метода - более "быстрый отклик" и отсутствие лишней нагрузки на сервер. Минусы - "палевно"))

Особых проблем при встройке этого в шаблон друпала быть не должно.